# Exoplayer - Widevine and MPEG DASH

Tags: mpeg-dash, exoplayer, widevine

I am trying to implement Android app for playing widevine-protected video. I build my application on Exoplayer and I have issue with `MediaDrm`.

```
android.media.MediaDrm$MediaDrmStateException: Failed to get key request: DRM vendor-defined error: -2998
            at android.media.MediaDrm.getKeyRequest(Native Method)
            at com.google.android.exoplayer.drm.StreamingDrmSessionManager.postKeyRequest(StreamingDrmSessionManager.java:370)
            at com.google.android.exoplayer.drm.StreamingDrmSessionManager.openInternal(StreamingDrmSessionManager.java:314)
            at com.google.android.exoplayer.drm.StreamingDrmSessionManager.open(StreamingDrmSessionManager.java:284)
            at com.google.android.exoplayer.MediaCodecTrackRenderer.maybeInitCodec(MediaCodecTrackRenderer.java:325)
            at com.google.android.exoplayer.MediaCodecTrackRenderer.onInputFormatChanged(MediaCodecTrackRenderer.java:739)
            at com.google.android.exoplayer.MediaCodecTrackRenderer.readFormat(MediaCodecTrackRenderer.java:511)
            at com.google.android.exoplayer.MediaCodecTrackRenderer.doSomeWork(MediaCodecTrackRenderer.java:492)
            at com.google.android.exoplayer.ExoPlayerImplInternal.doSomeWork(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:417)
            at com.google.android.exoplayer.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleMessage(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:205)
```

I have this exception. I found that this exception is thrown at this line of code:

```
keyRequest = mediaDrm.getKeyRequest(sessionId, schemeData, mimeType, MediaDrm.KEY_TYPE_STREAMING, params);
```

All parameters of method are set correctly, but calling of this method fails and thrown exception above.

Do you know how can I solve it? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solved it. The problem was with device, which I was using for testing. This device is Samsung Galaxy S4 with Android 5.0.1. When I tried my code on different device (Nexus 5, some Samsung tablet, etc.), it worked fine. So probably there is some bug or missing support of Widevine Modular in Galaxy S4.